# Saving uploaded image in database with relative path in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload an image and after uploading, I have to save the path of the image but it only saves the physical path in the database

> "C:\Oumaima\GMAOProject\GMAOProject\Images\Lighthouse.jpg".

What I want is to save it as a relative path in the database.

> "~\Images\Lighthouse.jpg"

This is the code in controller:

```cs
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Thank you

Comment: The best way to do this is stored it on disk and save the path in db.

Comment: I didn't understand .. Can you please to tell me how to do that and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save "~/Images/"+fileName. Server.Mappath will give you the physical path

Comment: it returns this error :  La méthode SaveAs est configurée pour nécessiter un chemin d'accès associé à une racine, et le chemin d'accès '~/Images\Hydrangeas.jpg' n'est pas associé à une racine.

Comment: Can you try to file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+fileName)) server.mappath gives you physical path and you should not use it for database records. buy saveas method needs physical path so you should use server.mappath at saving. And next time please post english errors:)

Comment: i'm sorry about th french message and i used your suggestion with just Path.combine("~/Images/"+fileName) and it works..Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named **wwwroot**, create another folder **Images** inside wwwroot folder

```
string fileName = "employee_01.jpg";
string folderName = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "Images");
var ImagePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
   
using (var imageFile = new FileStream(ImagePath , FileMode.Create))
    {
        imageFile.Write(bytess, 0, bytess.Length);
        imageFile.Flush();
    }
```

Image will be upload at relative path